# Composite number of occurrences of letter with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need regex for string, which contains **composite** number of consecutive letter **A**. By composite number is meant not prime number of letters. So **AAAAA** is not valid and **AAAAAAAAA** is valid.
My only solution for this:

```
import re
Regex_Pattern = r'(A{2,})\1+'
print(str(bool(re.search(Regex_Pattern, raw_input()))).lower())
```

But it doesn't work for occurrences of 9 letters **A**. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the whole string must be matched. So add `^` and `$`:

```
>>> [i for i in range(20) if re.search(r'^(A{2,})\1+$', 'A' * i)]
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18]
```

Or using `re.match`, you only need `$`:

```
>>> [i for i in range(20) if re.match(r'(A{2,})\1+$', 'A' * i)]
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, maybe you help me how to write variation of this regex, but minimum length of A should be 6 or greater?

Comment: Replace `2` with `3`.